# Apache .htaccess rewrite all but one

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have an Angular2 application, to get the routes working properly I've setup a rewrite in my .htaccess to point at /

Now my problem is that I need to redirect an API I wrote, which is not working with my current rewrite rules.

Here is my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off

RewriteRule ^/api$ http://127.0.0.1:8888/ [P,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/api/(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:8888/$1 [P,L]


RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [NC,L]
```

The first rewrite should let me hit my API at

HOSTNAME/v1/api/etc/etc/etc/someParam

and the second should let my Angular2 routes work.

Both of these rules are hitting my Angular2 application.

How do I make two rules where the first says /api/**** rewrites to localhost:8888/api/v1/....

And then everything else gets directed at my Angular2 application?

Answer (score 0):

You want to split this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/api/(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:8888/$1 [P,L]
```

Into two rules.

Solution:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/api/****$ http://localhost:8888/api/v1/... [P,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
ReweiteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api/****$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/api/(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:8888/$1 [P,L]
```

Of course, you've gotta replace `****` and `...` accordingly.

Comment: I tried this but /api/... get's redirected to /index.html.  Let's assume the following, I want to redirect https://somedomain.com/api/v1/endpoint to http://127.0.0.1/api/v1/endpoint, would your solution work?  I can't seem to get it to take while keeping my index.html rewrite rule

Comment: It should work, make sure that there aren't any .htaccess files within subdirectories because they **may** overwrite your parent directorie's .htaccess rules.